# How to get access to GitLab in Docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a `Docker` on `Windows7` machine. Now i want to install `GitLab` in `Docker` container:

```
docker pull docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-ce
docker run --name gitlab101 -h gitlab101 -p 8080:8080 -p 443:443 -d gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

But when i tried to access to: http://127.0.0.1:8080/ i got nothing.
What i miss in container configuration?
Or running `Gitlab` on Windows is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to run Gitlab from within the docker container. On Windows, you may have to switch to Linux containers. However, as this article mentions, they are not officially supporting docker windows [GitlabOnDockerWindows.](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/)

You should use the same `docker run` command they provided in the link. After that, here are a few things you can check after executing the run command:

First, check if the container is running with 
`docker ps` if you do not see your container running try

`docker ps -a`

-a  tag shows you all containers including exited ones. If the container exited you should check the logs with

`docker logs container_id`

if the container is running try getting the ip address with:

`docker inspect container_id | grep -i ipaddress`

Once you get the ip address try navigating to the address in the browser. Since you are mapping the ports, you can also use the ipaddress of your machine here.

You can find it by `ifconfig` on linux or `ipconfig` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've executed your command line (i'm using ubuntu) but it didn't work because of the https port so i changed it to 4443 (i don't know if you had this error or not).

fist of all, you have used gitlab101 as a hostname :

> -h gitlab101

So you have to check this url :  http://gitlab101:8080/ and not 127.0.0.1. But before, you have to add it to your local dns. in ubuntu i added it to /etc/hosts and if you are using windows then you can added it to [C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts]. you should have a response if you type ping gitlab101.

Check the requirement from this link (it can be a hardware issue) :

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html

And finally, have a look at the logs :

```
docker logs -f gitlab101
```

It takes about 10 minutes to set up this image the first time.